# How can I save extra PowerPoint Chart information in an XML

Tags: vsto, powerpoint, add-in, openxml

In my PowerPoint Add-in that creates different charts, I am drawing some shapes and lines to highlight different data and do some basic functionality.

Now, when the user saves the Presentation, I need to save the information related to these lines and shapes, as well as some of my chart properties. In my R&D, I have found that data can be saved in XML format inside a .pptx file because its an XML based format.

I can save my custom data in an XML file inside .pptx file pro grammatically by using `CustomXMLParts`.

```
string xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                   "<connectors xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/vsto/samples\">" +
                   "<connectorLine>" +
                   "<connectorLineIndex>1</connectorLineIndex>" +

                   ....

                   "</connectorLine>" +
                   "</connectors >";

Office.CustomXMLPart connectorXML = presentation.CustomXMLParts.Add(xmlString, missing);
```

This adds an XML in .pptx file.

Now, I am stuck. I need to read this XML file(and a couple of other XML files) when user opens the Presentation and draw the objects according to the data saved in the XML file.

How can I do this? Am I even doing it the right way? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It might be a great deal simpler to use Tags on your chart shape or on the slide that contains the chart.  If you're not familiar with them, search for "vba tags powerpoint" (leave out the quote marks) on google.  The first four or five results should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: The usual "Office" way is to embed an underlying XLSX containing the data. Have you explored updating that, then re-generating the chart?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, The Tags property is very helpful and I am using it in my code. But in the current scenario, like PowerPoint, I need to make an XML file (lets say MyChart.xml) and put the information about 'connectors', 'growth arrows' etc.

Comment: @JasonPlutext, I think the 'chart.xml' file can not be updated by code.